# Session handling in python / django

Tags: python, django, authentication, facebook

I am creating an application that lets users login using Google, Facebook and the website's native login. The site is being built in Python / Django.

What would be the best way to handle login, session management and user authentication?

I do not want to use the in-built Django user management. I am using Django very sparingly(URLs, templates)